# Theme changes after every other update (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, themes

The strangest thing is happening to me in Xubuntu 14.04. After every other update, my desktop theme is changing from this (Xubuntu default theme):

[image]

To this (not sure if this is actually a theme):

[image]

No idea on to what is triggering this strange change, that is reverted (again) after a few updates have been run.

Any thoughts on this?